# Calculate moving average as a sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a 26 week moving average for the total scrap value in a manufacturing metrics database. Currently the system has 4 data sources, so I created a table for each source. I then have a sub-query that goes through each table, union all the data between them, and reports the information summed by production week.

I've tried to incorporate this example that I found on another site:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (dt DATE, qty INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2007-1-1',5),
                     ('2007-1-2',6),
                     ('2007-1-3',7),
                     ('2007-1-4',8),
                     ('2007-1-5',9),
                     ('2007-1-6',10),
                     ('2007-1-7',11),
                     ('2007-1-8',12),
                     ('2007-1-9',13);

SELECT 
  t1.dt, 
  ( SELECT SUM(t2.qty) / COUNT(t2.qty)
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE DATEDIFF(t1.dt, t2.dt) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
  ) AS '5dayMovingAvg'
FROM t AS t1
ORDER BY t1.dt;
```

I was able to incorporate that code but I had to run the large query twice in order to get a proper result (once in the select area and again in from). Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
SELECT 
  date_format(t1.date, '%Y') as year, date_format(t1.date, '%m') as month, date_format(t1.date, '%d') as day, t1.epc, t1.scrap, t1.freight, t1.smo, t1.ext_sort, t1.total, 
  ( SELECT SUM(t2.total) / COUNT(t2.total)
    FROM 

   (SELECT date, sum(epc_labor_cost) as epc, sum(scrap_value) as scrap, sum(prem_freight_cost) as freight, sum(smo_sort_hours) as smo, sum(ext_sort) as ext_sort, sum(epc_labor_cost+scrap_value+prem_freight_cost+smo_sort_hours+ext_sort) as total FROM (
                                           select pn, date, labor_cost as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from epc_data 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, abs(value) as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from scrap 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, cost as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from prem_freight 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, hours*4.02 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from smo_sort
                                union all select STRIP_NON_DIGIT(ext_sort.pn) as pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, (ext_sort.sorted*pn_data.ext_sort_cost) as ext_sort, 0 as total from ext_sort inner join pn_data on STRIP_NON_DIGIT(ext_sort.pn)=STRIP_NON_DIGIT(pn_data.pn) ) as test group by year(date), week(date,3) ORDER BY date desc) as t2
    WHERE DATEDIFF(t1.date, t2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 92
  ) AS movavg
FROM (SELECT date, sum(epc_labor_cost) as epc, sum(scrap_value) as scrap, sum(prem_freight_cost) as freight, sum(smo_sort_hours) as smo, sum(ext_sort) as ext_sort, sum(epc_labor_cost+scrap_value+prem_freight_cost+smo_sort_hours+ext_sort) as total FROM (
                                           select pn, date, labor_cost as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from epc_data 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, abs(value) as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from scrap 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, cost as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from prem_freight 
                                 union all select pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, hours*4.02 as smo_sort_hours, 0 as ext_sort, 0 as total from smo_sort
                                union all select STRIP_NON_DIGIT(ext_sort.pn) as pn, date, 0 as epc_labor_cost, 0 as scrap_value, 0 as prem_freight_cost, 0 as smo_sort_hours, (ext_sort.sorted*pn_data.ext_sort_cost) as ext_sort, 0 as total from ext_sort inner join pn_data on STRIP_NON_DIGIT(ext_sort.pn)=STRIP_NON_DIGIT(pn_data.pn) ) as test group by year(date), week(date,3) ORDER BY date desc) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.date desc limit
```

Comment: my apologies, first time posting for help - I can't seem to find how to format the mysql query so that it shows up appropriately on stackoverflow. Guidance on that would be appreciated too.

Comment: Formatting your query is just a matter of taking the time to enter it cleanly, then highlighting that and using the "Code Sample" formatting option to keep the normal text layout mechanics from hiding that formatting.

Comment: Sidenote: Selecting things like `date_format(date, '%Y')` while GROUPing on `year(date), week(date,3)` may cause you problems. The default configurations of more recent versions of MySQL will not even permit it, nor will many other RDMBS; and even when it is allowed, you can't be certain which day of the week will be used. You're technically not even guaranteed `date_format(date, '%Y')` and `date_format(date, '%m')` will even use the same value from `date`; you should replace your `date_format(date, 'stuff')` with `date_format(min(date), 'stuff')`

Comment: Thank you Uueerdo, I will look into the date_format change